draw arc with big arrow between two point
I would like to draw a arc with big arrow like below:

I have try below code with big arrow!
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  fat arrow/.style={
    every to/.style={
      to path={
        let \p1 = ($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
            \n2 = {mod(scalar(atan2(\y1,\x1))+360, 360)}
        in
        -- (\tikztotarget)
        node[draw, blue,
             inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=5pt,
             minimum height=\n1-\pgflinewidth,
             single arrow,
             rotate=\n2, 
             anchor=tip,
             #1 
             ]
          {} \tikztonodes}
  }},
  fat arrow/.default=
]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \path[fat arrow] (B) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Current output:


Instead of trying to modify a predefined shape, draw a line with an arrow head:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \draw[->,line width=0.3cm,color=blue!30,arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:0.5cm]}] (B) to[in=45,out=135] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


